# Prove if $\lim_{n\to +\infty} \int_0^T f_n(t) dt=0$ holds or not

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $(\varepsilon)_n$ be an infinitesimal sequence.
If I have
$$-\varepsilon_n\le \liminf_{n\to +\infty}-\int_0^T f_n(t) dt = -\limsup_{n\to +\infty}\int_0^T f_n(t) dt,$$
can I conclude that
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty} \int_0^T f_n(t) dt=0.$$

Honestly, I don't know how to proceed in this case.

Could someone please help me?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Certainly if $f_{n}\geq 0$ for every $n$, then you would have $0\leq\liminf_{n}\int_{0}^{T}f_{n}(t)dt\leq\limsup_{n}\int_{0}^{T}f_{n}(t)dt\leq\varepsilon_{n}$ which is enough to conclude that $\lim_{n}\int_{0}^{T}f_{n}(t)dt$ exists and equals zero.